# I got past "aidl missing' in android studios and now have 7 new errors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I used to have the aidle missing error then I started using ice cream sandwhich api and build tool 1.9.1.0 which I got 7 errors similar to the ones I list (copied and pasted). I don't know what is wrong i'm using ubuntu 14.04 and am using android studio. I have done and researched everything I can.

```
Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.

Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.

Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.

Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.

Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
```

Any leads at all will help.

Answer (score 1):

`android:textAlignment` was add in android 4.2

try `android:gravity`

and the same for the rest

check this for more information http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html